# Don't open OGG file

Tags: javascript, html, audio, ogg

I open OGG file with html5 (audio tag).
On one site works, the other does not. Why?

For example: 
http://devluntegg.fishok.getmyip.com:39875/webim/sounds/new_user.ogg - work (play)
http://lovisnami.ru/webim/sounds/new_user.ogg - don't work (proposes to maintain)

html and js same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first URL returns

```
Content-Type: audio/ogg
```

the second one

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

different web server setup.

Comment: Specifically where it is necessary to register?

Comment: I see, it's nginx. Probably /etc/nginx/mime.types or similar.

Comment: There's no `.htaccess` in nginx.

Answer (score 0):

Only one of those is an ogg file. The other is a blob of binary data.

(At least, that is what the servers tell the browsers).

You need to configure the server correctly.

```
user@host:~ # curl -I http://devluntegg.fishok.getmyip.com:39875/webim/sounds/new_user.ogg | grep Content
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0 13889    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
Content-Length: 13889
Content-Type: audio/ogg

user@host:~ # curl -I http://lovisnami.ru/webim/sounds/new_user.ogg  | grep Content  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0 13889    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 13889
```